# Remote Desktop Mouse Function

Tags: remote-desktop

I have set up my mouse on my computer to use the right click as the primary button.  I want the same set up on my remote desktop. However the changes don't pull over to the remote desktop.  How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Access the system through remote desktop.

Open the configuration of the mouse, and set the right click as the primary. Depending on the operating system, one of the following:

WINDOWS

Control Panel -> Mouse -> Buttons -> Button Configuration -> Set primary button

LINUX GNOME

Settings -> Devices -> Mouse and touchpad -> Set primary button

Comment: Although this is technically correct, this answer would greatly benefit from rewording it so a non-techie user could follow it step-by-step. For that reason, I won't vote this answer up.

Comment: +1 :) This makes it so much better for other people to work with it.